# Convergence of probabilties with indicator function

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{p_j\}_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ be a set of nonnegative values such that they all sum to $1$, let $\mathcal{B}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of the countable sample space $S = \{s_1, s_2, \dots\}$, and let $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite sequence of disjoint subsets in $\mathcal{B}$.

We define $$\mathbf{1}_{A_i}(s_j) = \begin{cases}
1, & s_j \in A_i \\
0, & s_j \notin A_i\text{.}
\end{cases}$$
What justifies the equivalence
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}p_j\cdot \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(s_j) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}p_j\cdot \mathbf{1}_{A_i}(s_j)\text{?}$$
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/342060/81560) talks a bit in brief about this, but the given link has a 404 error.

Comment: One can always interchange summation signs when every entry is nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_{mn} \geq 0$, then

$$\sum_m \sum_n a_{mn} = \sum_n \sum_m a_{mn}$$

by [Tonelli's theorem for non-negative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions)

Convergence is not necessary. See: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863937/proving-sigma-additivity-and-interchanging-order-of-summation-integration-jus) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519751/why-cant-fubinis-tonellis-theorem-for-non-negative-functions-extend-to-genera/1519769) [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172306/can-we-switch-integral-and-expectation-by-fubinis-theorem) [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444870/is-a-certain-kind-of-continuity-needed-on-joint-pdfs-to-switch-order-of-integrat)