# Is a certain kind of continuity needed on joint pdfs to switch order of integration?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, continuity, expectation

Iirc, one of my professors offered the following proof for total expectation:

> If $X \in L^1 (\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ has pdf $f_X$ and $Y
> > \in L^1 (\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ has pdf $f_Y$, then
>   $E[E[X|Y]] = E[X]$, assuming $f_{X|Y=y}$ exists.

Pf: $LHS = \int_\mathbb{R} (E[X|Y=y]) f_Y(y) dy$

$=\int_\mathbb{R} (\int_\mathbb{R} x f_{X|Y=y} (x)) f_Y(y) dy$

$=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} x f_{X|Y=y} (x) dx f_Y(y) dy$

$=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} x f_{XY} (x,y) dx dy$

$=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} x f_{XY}(x,y) dy dx$ (*)

$=\int_\mathbb{R} x \int_\mathbb{R} f_{XY}(x,y) dy dx$

$=\int_\mathbb{R} x f_X dx$

$=RHS$

QED

Is that right?

If it is wrong, why?

If it is right, what is the justification for (*)?

I thought the justification is that

$$\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) dx dy = \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y) dy dx$$

$\because f(x,y) \geq 0$ and by [Tonelli's theorem for non-negative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions)

but actually it may not extend to saying that

$$\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \color{red}{x} f(x,y) dx dy = \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \color{red}{x} f(x,y) dy dx$$

since $X \geq 0$ is not assumed.

My professor said that it has something to do with uniform or Lipschitz continuity. Does it?

Comment: If the random variables are $L^1$, you can use Fubini's theorem to switch the order of integration.

Comment: @yarmenti How? $ $

Comment: FYI, in general, $$E[E[X|Y]] \ne \int_\mathbb{R} E[X|Y] f_Y(y) dy=E[X|Y] .$$

Comment: @Did Why? It looks to be the same as in the discrete case [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_discrete_case).

Comment: Yeah--except that since you copy things without knowing their definitions, slips do occur, which make that what you write and what you are copying from are two different matters.

Comment: Maybe a problem of notation, I guess Did wants to say that: $E(E(X|Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} E(X|Y=y) f_Y(y) dy$ ...

Comment: @Did I didn't copy from the discrete case :P I tried to rewrite the proof from memory. So is it just the $= y$ ?

Comment: Second problem (more serious, and already explained in details multiple times to you): in your setting, the object $f_{X\mid Y=y}$ might not exist at all.

Comment: @yarmenti Thanks! Again how can we use Fubini's?

Comment: @Did Thanks! Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is non-negative when $x$ is non-negative, and $-x\;f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is non-negative when $x$ is negative, we can apply [Tonelli's Theorem for non negative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) by separating the integral into two.

$$\begin{align}\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R x\;f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y & =\int_\Bbb R\left(\int_{\Bbb R^+} x f_{X,Y}(x,y) \operatorname d x-\int_{\Bbb R^-} (-x)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\right)\operatorname d y \\[1ex] ~ & = \int_{\Bbb R^+} x\int_{\Bbb R}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x-\int_{\Bbb R^-}(-x)\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \\[1ex] ~ & = \int_\Bbb R x\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\end{align}$$