# Why can't Fubini's/Tonelli's theorem for non-negative functions extend to general functions?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, examples-counterexamples

[Challenging-conventional-wisdom](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/ask-yourself-dumb-questions-%E2%80%93-and-answer-them/) question based on [an answer to my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1444964/140308).

If $X \in L^1 (\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ has pdf $f_X$, $Y \in L^1 (\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ has pdf $f_Y$, and they have joint pdf $f_{XY}(x,y)$, we can say that:

Since $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is non-negative when $x$ is non-negative, and $-x\;f_{XY}(x,y)$ is non-negative when $x$ is negative, we can apply [Tonelli's/Fubini's Theorem for non negative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) by separating the integral into two.

$$\begin{align}\int_\Bbb R\int_\Bbb R x\;f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y & =\int_\Bbb R\left(\int_{\Bbb R^+} x f_{XY}(x,y) \operatorname d x-\int_{\Bbb R^-} (-x)f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname d x\right)\operatorname d y \\[1ex] ~ & = \int_{\Bbb R^+} x\int_{\Bbb R}f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x-\int_{\Bbb R^-}(-x)\int_\Bbb R f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \\[1ex] ~ & = \int_\Bbb R x\int_\Bbb R f_{XY}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\end{align}$$

Soooooo why can't we just decompose every integrand like extending from nonnegative functions to general functions like in Lebesgue integrals i.e. the following?

$$\int \int g(x,y) dx dy =  \int \int g^{+}(x,y) dx dy + \int \int g^{-}(x,y) dx dy$$

What exactly is the problem otherwise? Counterexample pls? I'm guessing in three dimensions '$g^{+}(x,y)$' or '$g^{-}(x,y)$' don't necessarily exist. Not quite sure how I would define those. I guess the integrand must change sign w/rt at most 1 variable in order for Tonelli's/Fubini's to apply?

Comment: Why are you not happy with the answer given by Tryss? And why the edit that made the writing worse?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker 1. No reply to my comments yet 2. I just put the '?' up...

Comment: 1. You are asking for an explanation of notation you have used yourself. 2. You replaced "i.e." with "like as follows" too.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker 1. LOL I no longer remember why I asked that. 2. K fine but no reply for other question

Answer (score 7):

You can do this... But only if either $\int\int g^+(x,y) dxdy$ or $\int\int g^-(x,y) dxdy$ is finite. Indeed, if both are infinite,

$$\int\int g(x,y) dxdy = \int\int g^+(x,y) dxdy - \int\int g^-(x,y) dxdy = (+\infty) - (+ \infty) = ???$$

So, basically, if you show that $\int\int |g(x,y)| dxdy < \infty$, then you can switch the order of integration.

Comment: Thanks Tryss. Interesting. What is $g^{+}(x,y)$ exactly? $g^{+}(x,y) = max(g(x,y),0)$? So Fubini's/Tonelli's theorem really does hold for any finite integrand? [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863937/proving-sigma-additivity-and-interchanging-order-of-summation-integration-jus) [2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172306/can-we-switch-integral-and-expectation-by-fubinis-theorem)